# Java/JavaFX - Shopping Cart System - Tokenizing data into an Arraylist

Tags: java, javafx, arraylist, tokenize

So I'm working on a school assignment. I have to create a shopping cart system that displays books in a `ListView` and have buttons/menu items that can add those books to a cart or remove them.

The program is supposed to read a file "BookPrices.txt" and tokenize the strings, separating the words from the digits and then add them to two Arraylists. One `Arraylist` is for the book titles and the other is for the book prices.

The problem that I'm having is that the tokenizer code doesn't seem to be working. I tested the arraylists with some printlns in the addItemButton to see if there is anything in the arrays and so far they appear empty. Keep in mind the tokenizer code was given to me from the textbook and the full program is still missing code for manipulating data and calculating a total cost.

Assignment:
Create an application that works like a shopping cart system for an online book store.
When your application being execution, it should read the contents of the file and store
the book titles in a ListView. The user should be able to select a title from the list
and add it to a "shopping cart", which is simply another ListView control. The application
should have buttonsor menu items that allow the user to remove items from the shopping
cart, clear the shopping cart of all selections, and check out. When the user checks out,
the application should calculate and display the subtotal of all the books in the shopping
cart, the sales tax (which is 7 percent of the subtotal), and the total.

BookPrices.txt:

```
I Did It Your Way,11.95
The History of Scotland,14.50
Learn Calculus in One Day,29.95
Feel the Stress,18.50
Great Poems,12.95
Europe on a Shoestring,10.95
The Life of Mozart,14.50
```

Code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class ShoppingCartSystem extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

        ArrayList<String> inventoryTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Double> inventoryPrices = new ArrayList<Double>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Label myLabel = new Label("Select books to purchase.");
      Label subTotalLabel = new Label("Checkout:");
      Label taxLabel = new Label("Checkout:");
      Label cartTotalLabel = new Label("Checkout:");
      
      // test inventoryTitles.add("Bob");
        
      
      ObservableList<String> titleList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(inventoryTitles);
      
        ListView<String> storelist = new ListView<>(titleList);
      
       storelist.setPrefSize(170,170);
      
        storelist.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
      
        //storelist.getItems().addAll(titleList);
         
         //storelist.getItems().addAll("I Did it Your Way: $11.95", "The History of Scotland: $14.50",
            //      "Learn Calculus in One Day: $29.95", "Feel the Stress: $18.50", "Great Poems: $12.95",
            //      "Europe on a Shoestring: $10.95", "The Life of Mozart: $14.50");

        ListView<String> cartlist = new ListView<>();
      cartlist.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        cartlist.setPrefSize(170,170);

        Button addItemButton = new Button("Add an item");
        addItemButton.setOnAction(event ->
        {
            ObservableList<String> selections =
            storelist.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

         for (String str : selections)
            cartlist.getItems().addAll(str);

            System.out.println(inventoryTitles);
         System.out.println(inventoryPrices);
        
        });

        Button removeItemButton = new Button("Remove an item");
        removeItemButton.setOnAction(event ->
        {
         ObservableList<String> selections2 =
            cartlist.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
         
         cartlist.getItems().removeAll(selections2);
        });

        Button clearCartButton = new Button("Clear Cart");
        clearCartButton.setOnAction(event ->
        {
         cartlist.getItems().setAll();  
        });

        Button checkoutButton = new Button("Check Out");
        checkoutButton.setOnAction(event ->
        {
            //Check out code, maths
         final double Tax_Rate = 0.07;
         
         //Int Sales Tax = Subtotal * 7;
         
         //Final total = Sales Tax + Total;
         
         //checkoutLabel.setText("Subtotal, Sales Tax, Total");
        });
   
      VBox vbox = new VBox(10, storelist, cartlist, addItemButton, 
                           removeItemButton, clearCartButton, checkoutButton);
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);    
      
      Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 800, 800);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Online Bookstore");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
   
   private void readBookFile() throws IOException
   {
      String input;  // To hold a line from the file
      
      // Open the file.
      File file = new File("BookPrices.txt");
      Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);
      
      // Read the file.
      while (inFile.hasNext())
      {
         // Read a line.
         input = inFile.nextLine();
         
         // Tokenize the line.
         String[] tokens = input.split(",");
         
         // Add the book info to the ArrayLists.
         inventoryTitles.add(tokens[10]);
         inventoryPrices.add(Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]));
      }
      
      // Close the file.
      inFile.close();
   
   }
   
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that the tokenizer code doesn't seem to be working. I tested the arraylists with some printlns in the `addItemButton` to see if there is anything in the arrays, and so far they appear empty. Keep in mind the tokenizer code was given to me from the textbook and the full program is still missing code for manipulating data and calculating a total cost.

Answer (score 1):

From your code this is what I observed:

- There is no call to your `readBookFile()` method in application. I believe you need to first call the method at the first line of your start() method.
- The initialization of File object is a bit problematic if your file is in the same package. Currently it refers to the project root location. If your file is in the same package, I would suggest to use the Path API.
- Finally there is a typo error in loading the first string. It is mentioned as `tokens[10]` instead of `tokens[0]`

Once your correct all these three, then your code works.
[image]

```
private void readBookFile() {
    String input;  // To hold a line from the file
    // Open the file.
    Scanner inFile = null;
    try {
        Path p = Paths.get(getClass().getResource("BookPrices.txt").toURI());
        inFile = new Scanner(p.toFile());
    } catch (URISyntaxException | FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    // Read the file.
    while (inFile.hasNext()) {
        // Read a line.
        input = inFile.nextLine();

        // Tokenize the line.
        String[] tokens = input.split(",");

        // Add the book info to the ArrayLists.
        inventoryTitles.add(tokens[0]);
        inventoryPrices.add(Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]));
    }
    // Close the file.
    inFile.close();
}
```